# Repeat Angular promise based on results?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-promise

I have an AngularJS function that grabs some data from the database.  Based on how the data is populated to the database, I won't get some of the data I'm looking for right away (I do get the data back within a second or two of my original call).  What I would like to do is check the results that came back from the database, and if the certain type isn't there yet, to "push another promise" that will get the data from the database again.  Here is my function so far:

```
         function getResponses(ids,user) {
            var deferred = $q.defer();
            var promises = [];
            var idsString = "";

            angular.forEach(ids, function (id) {
                idsString += "," + id;
            });

            idsString = idsString.substring(1);

            //Get Response calls retrieves the data from the database
            promises.push(getResponse(idsString, user));

            $q.all(promises).then(function(results) {
                deferred.resolve(results);
            });

            return deferred.promise;
        }
```

My biggest question so far is where would I put the "check results" part?  I'm thinking it would go in the $q.all block, but would I need to resolve the results from the database first, or would I just check the results from the database and if they contains all of the necessary types, resolve it then?  And if it isn't resolved, just keep pushing the getResponse promise in an $interval until the desired results come back?

Is what I'm asking for even possible?

Thanks

Comment: So, basically you want to poll the database for a value of the specific type? If so, it would be more logical to create a function that takes a type parameter and resolves that specific value. That way you can create an array of promises, await them all, and when they've all resolved you have your values.

Answer (score 0):

There is no need to manufacture a promise with `$q.defer` because `$q.all` already returns a promise:

```
 function getResponses(ids,user) {
    //var deferred = $q.defer();
    var promises = [];
    var idsString = "";

    angular.forEach(ids, function (id) {
        idsString += "," + id;
    });

    idsString = idsString.substring(1);

    //Get Response calls retrieves the data from the database
    promises.push(getResponse(idsString, user));

    /* NOT needed
    $q.all(promises).then(function(results) {
        deferred.resolve(results);
    });

    return deferred.promise;
    */

    //INSTEAD return promise from $q.all
    return $q.all(promises);
}
```